# memory is being allocated each time i navigate to a new fragment

Tags: android

I thought Navigation handled this in the background. How can I manage the number of allocated instances explicitly?

from the android profiler -> number of fragments currently allocated in memory.
[image]

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {


    if(user.isAnonymous() && menuItem.getItemId() != R.id.homeFragment){
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navigationHostFragment).navigate(R.id.restrictedViewFragment);
        return true;
    }

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.homeFragment:
            Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navigationHostFragment).navigate(R.id.homeFragment);
            return true;

        case R.id.newPostFragment:
            Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navigationHostFragment).navigate(R.id.newPostFragment);
            return true;

        case R.id.myJobsFragment:
            Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navigationHostFragment).navigate(R.id.myJobsFragment);
            return true;

        case R.id.myProfileFragment:
            Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navigationHostFragment).navigate(R.id.myProfileFragment);
            return true;

    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to keep `break` in each and every case statement, replace those `return true` lines. Also, the last `return false ` statement is not needed. Probably the first line could go in the default case of the switch

Comment: the return type for the method is a boolean, forgive if I am wrong, but the return will exit the method entirely correct?